# Ruby - Running rb files from script (2)

Tags: ruby

I'd like to write a ruby script that then calls another ruby script. Example, I'd like to run the "test1.rb" from my script. The test1.rb has been simplified to just do this:

```
print "1"
```

Then get the result (-> 1).

I ask to help others to fix this problem, and they suggested the popen3 command:

```
require 'open3'
cmd = 'ruby "test1.rb"'
puts Dir.pwd
Open3.popen3(cmd) do |stdin, stdout|
    var = stdout.read
    puts var
end
```

However, the script send an error message:

```
X:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/open3.rb:193:in `spawn': No such file or directory
- ruby "test1.rb" (Errno::ENOENT)
```

Please help me.

Comment: Did you try `puts \`ruby "test1.rb"\` `? The backticks run the command and return the output.

Comment: Yes, but it sends an error message too.

Comment: [file-path]:1:in ``': No such file or directory - ruby "test1.rb" (Errno::ENOENT)

Comment: They are not in the same directory, you should use relative or absolute path.

Comment: Double check that you have `test1.rb` actually in the correct directory. I can make it run using your exact code as long as I have the test ruby script in the correct folder.

Comment: I checked, but the main script and test1.rb file is on the same folder.

Comment: I think this is the biggest joke today.

Comment: Otherwise I use Ruby 2.2.0 on Windows 7.